# My first MVC project yields odd error; it stops in the middle of a comment. Why is that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to learn MVC, using VS 2012. I've created a simple Intranet application, and added entity framework. Because I wanted to just start learning I added only 1 table (named Providers) from a SQL Server database. Then I added a controller for Providers table (I believe EF renamed Providers to simply Provider). Then I generated the views for the Provider controller. However, something very strange is going on with the code. When I run it, it fails, but it stops on a line of code that I've commented out?! What in heck is going on? Here's a screen image of the error:

[image]

Here's the code for the Index() for the ProviderController class:

```
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View(db.Providers.ToList());
        //var currentProviders = from p in db.Providers
        //                       where p.ContractIsCurrent == true && p.Facility == 1
        //                       orderby p.ContractName
        //                       select p;
        var currentProviders = db.Providers.Where(c => c.ContractIsCurrent && c.Facility == 1)
                                            .OrderBy(c => c.ContractName)
                                            .ToList();

        return View(currentProviders);
    }
```

and in case you want to see it, here's the link to the whole project (it doesn't include the change that I have listed above):

[Link on my OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1imNtki)

Comment: What happens if you remove these comments ?
Do you have two Provider classes in the assembly ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your pdb file is out of sink.

Clean your solution and ReBuild the application. should fix this

Comment: Rebuilding a solution I can easily do - have done it many times before. But cleaning a solution; I've never done that. How do I do that?

Comment: Like the build solution. Right click the solution and select "Clean Solution"